# Why can I use gets() in gcc -std=c11?

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer, c11, gets

The `gets()` function has been removed from the C language. No such function exists in the standard.

Yet I compile the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  (void) gets (NULL);
}
```

using

```
gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra
```

and it compiles without giving any errors or warnings. Similarly,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gets;

int main (void)
{}
```

will not compile (error: 'gets' redeclared as different kind of symbol).

In the standard 4. Conformance §6 we can read:

> A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional
>   library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any
>   strictly conforming program

Given the above I don't think gcc is standard-compliant, even in pedantic mode. Is there a reason for this? Is this intentional or is it a bug?

GCC version 4.9.1.

Edit:

```
gcc --version
gcc (x86_64-win32-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.1
```

Comment: GCC 4.8.2 here. In pedantic mode the first snippet will not compiler because `gets` is never defined. In non-pedantic mode I get `warning: the \`gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.`. The second snippet is not an issue, because nothing prevents you from declaring a symbol called `gets`. For instance, `int printf;` is perfectly legal. Am I missing the point of the question?

Comment: What `libc` are you using? In Unix-like systems standard C library is shipped with OS. For example, in Linux it is usually _glibc_, which was removed `gets` in version 2.16

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo You seem to be missing the point regarding the second half, it shouldn't fail (`gets` shouldn't collide with anything), but it does.

Comment: I'm for a bug specific to gcc 4.9.1 as version 4.8.2 and > 4.9.2 do fail.

Comment: @unwind thanks. Actually in my case it doesn't, so I'd call it a library mismatch or compiler bug, but I don't want to jump to conclusions :\

Comment: In case it matters, it is Mingw for 64 bit Windows. I'm using the default lib that came with the download. Is there a way I can check the lib version?

Comment: MinGW uses Microsoft's standard library, which does not even support C99 properly.

Comment: @interjay Seriously? Then how can any modern C at all work in Mingw? I thought MS had dropped C support long time ago, let alone C11 support.

Comment: @interjay: It is funny, considering that Microsoft has properly removed `gets` from their libraries.

Comment: @Lundin: Microsoft is devotedly supporting C language in their compilers. I don't know where you got the idea that "MS had dropped C support".

Comment: @haccks: No, gcc has never supported `gets` -- or `fgets` for that matter. If `gets` is supported by a given implementation, it's implemented by the library, not by the compiler.

Comment: @KeithThompson; My wording was wrong. It is still present GNU C library.

Comment: @haccks: Yes and no. In the `<stdio.h>` header provided by the GNU C library, `gets` is still declared, but the declaration is surrounded by `#if !defined __USE_ISOC1` ... `#endif`. The *implementation* is still there, but in a way that permits user code to define a function with the same name.

Comment: Backwards compatibility — programs exist that use `gets()`, and it is deemed better to let them run than to prevent them running.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

gcc is just the compiler, not the entire implementation.

On my system (Linux Mint 17.3, gcc 4.8.4, GNU libc 2.19), I get:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -c c.c
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:5:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   (void) gets (NULL);
   ^
```

To correctly diagnose the error, the *implementation* needs to be conforming. That means both the compiler (which never provided `gets` in the first place) and the library.

You're using a library that still provides the `gets` function. Because of that the *implementation* as a whole (which consists of the compiler gcc, the library, and a few other pieces) does not conform to C11.

Bottom line: This is not a gcc issue, and there's not much that gcc can do about it. (Well, it *could* issue a special-case diagnostic for `gets`, but then it would have to determine that it's not a valid call to a user-defined function with the same name.)

Comment: Though C standard library droped `gets`, GNU C library still includes this function.

Comment: Copying my response to your other comment: @haccks: Yes and no. In the <stdio.h> header provided by the GNU C library, gets is still declared, but the declaration is surrounded by #if !defined __USE_ISOC1 ... #endif. The implementation is still there, but in a way that permits user code to define a function with the same name.

Comment: OK. Do you consider this as a bug?

Comment: @haccks: It's a failure of this particular implementation (MinGW) to conform to the C11 standard. (See also MinGW's problems with `long double`, something that applies to C90, C99, and C11.) Sure, I'd say it's a bug. (But it's an easily avoidable one -- don't use `gets`, even if your compiler fails to warn you about it.)

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I am glad you came to this post almost after an year (little bit surprised!!) to share this information.

Comment: @haccks: I didn't even notice the date until you mentioned it. I think it showed up on my front page because somebody else posted an answer.

Comment: Oh! I can see now.

Answer (score 1):

The key line of your code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Did you update your system's C library and headers?  They're also part of the C implementation, along with the compiler.

Comment: I did run `mingw-get update` and `mingw-get upgrade`, same error afterwards.

Comment: As Andrew mentioned, the key line is the #include <stdio.h>. You should find and analyze the stdio.h file that is used by gcc to perform the compilation. That file probably still has the gets function defined.

Answer (score 1):

**update** this may not be an answer to the question, I try to make it informational.

I happened to find that gcc mentioned **gets** is not following C11 standard for some library issue `glibc 2.16`.

See gcc supporting status of C11: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status
[image: croped from the above link]

But I cannot find the definition of "library issue" and current status for other versions of glibc.

So I tried on my machine ubuntu16.04 with gcc version `5.3.1 20160413`, glibc version `Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23` 
We can get enough warning on compile time, but it's still OK to execute the output object file for "Backwards compatibility".

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

Comment: This is misleading.  gcc didn't remove `gets` because gcc never provided `gets` in the first place. It's provided by the library, not by the compiler (which why that status page refers to it as a "library issue").

Comment: @Keith Thompson. Thanks for the answer! That's amazing clear and helpful :).