# Why is implicit declaration of gets() not allowed in C99?

Tags: c, clang, c99, cs50, gets

I am starting to learn programming in C language the book I am refering to code shows some source code with `gets()` and my IDLE recognises it as well. But still while compiling it, my compiler doesn't agree with it.

Can anyone help me out? I am using `gets()` in the main function and using clang as the compiler.

Comment: Probably because `gets` has been removed alltogether. What is the __exact__ error message you get? I'm pretty sure it's a linker error. And __never__ use implicit declararions, they are a leftover from the last century.

Comment: @Mr. Anderson The function gets is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard any more. Use instead the function fgets. You can find its description in internet.

Comment: string0.c:8:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'gets' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    gets(s1);
    ^

Comment: @Mr.Anderson OK, so that' is actually a compiler error. Apparently the C compiler you use doesn't allow implicit declarations at all, which is s good thing. The `gets` function has bee deprecated some 20 years ago. Just don't use it. Read [__this__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it did work. Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thank you very much for help. :-)

Comment: Three things.  1: Implicit declarations were only ever valid for functions returning `int`; `gets()` returned `char *`, so an implicit declaration of `gets()` is wrong regardless.  2: As of C99, implicit declarations are no longer allowed *at all*.  3: `gets()` has been removed from the standard library as of C2011 because it is *dangerous* and *will* introduce a point of failure in your code.  Never use it, not even in toy code.

Comment: @JohnBode I wish modern C libraries would implement `gets` as `char *gets(char *s) { return strcpy(s, "Never use gets!"); }`.

Comment: "the book I am refering to code shows some source code with gets()" Try to burn the book and see if that solves the problem. Get a book written this millennia instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on my comment:

First, *never* use `gets()`, for any reason, even in toy code.  If you see it in an example program, ignore the example and move on.  It was deprecated in C99 and removed from the standard library *completely* in C2011 because it was a major security hole.  The heartburn caused by that one function was worth breaking 30-some-odd years of legacy code.

Second, under C89 and earlier, if the compiler saw a function *call* before it saw a declaration or definition, it would assume the function returned `int` - IOW, the function had an *implicit* declaration of `int`.  If you had a function *definition* later in the same translation unit, and the function returned an `int`, you were fine:

```
int foo( void )
{
  int x = bar(); // bar *implicitly* declared to return int
}

int bar( void ) // implicit declaration matches definition, we're good
{
  return some_integer_value;
}
```

However, if `bar` did *not* return an `int`, you'd get an error because the implicit `int` declaration did not match up with the non-`int` definition.

`gets()` returns `char *`, not `int`, so an implicit declaration of `gets` is incorrect *regardless*.

C99 removed implicit `int` declarations entirely - since then, *all* functions must be declared or defined before they are called.

**EDIT**

The most likely reason you're getting that implicit declaration error is that your compiler is recent enough that it no longer has a declaration for `gets` in `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a message like "implicit declaration of gets is not allowed" for the same reason you'd get the message "implicit declaration of my_undeclared_function is not allowed" if you tried to call `my_undeclared_function`.  These days, `gets` is not a standard C library function.

To explain in more detail: in modern C, if you write

```
int main()
{
    f();
}

int f()
{
    return 0;
}
```

you will typically get a message like "implicit declaration of function 'f' is invalid in C99".  Once upon a time, if you called a function the compiler hadn't heard of (yet), it assumed it was going to be a function returning `int`, but that assumption was removed in C99.

On the other hand, if you write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char line[100];
    printf("type something:\n");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    printf("you typed: %s", line);
    return 0;
}
```

you will *not* get that message about the functions `printf` and `fgets`.  These *are* functions that the compiler has heard of: their declarations are in `<stdio.h>`.

But if you write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char line[100];
    printf("type something:\n");
    gets(line);
    printf("you typed: %s", line);
    return 0;
}
```

you will get the message again, about function `gets()`, because `gets` is not a function the compiler has heard of.  It is not a standard function; it is not declared in `<stdio.h>`.

Now, once upon a time, `gets` was a standard function and it was declared in `<stdio.h>`, but it was a spectacularly ill-conceived and dangerous function, so it has been removed from the standard.  The book you read recommending it is quite out-of-date.

Comment: This isn't correct. `gets` was just flagged as obsolete in C99, it was not removed from the language.

Comment: @Lundin I didn't say that `gets` was removed from the language in C99.  I wasn't sure when it was removed, but if you say it was C11, I believe you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't `#include <stdio.h>`, simple as that.

In C99, you get the error if you use this exact code:

```
int main (void)
{
  char buf[10];
  gets(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Including stdio.h fixes the problem. Though notably, `gets` was flagged as an obsolete function in C99 and removed entirely from the language in C11. So the following code will not compile in standard C (C11):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  char buf[10];
  gets(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

So possibly you could get the error because you compile as standard C instead of C99.

(Note that the Windows Mingw compiler specifically might use a C11 compiler but a C99 standard lib, so you may get some [odd outcomes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619780/why-can-i-use-gets-in-gcc-std-c11) with that one.)

See [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) for details.