# Are there any substitutes for the gets() function in c99?

Tags: c, gets

[Why is implicit declaration of gets() not allowed in C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256131/why-is-implicit-declaration-of-gets-not-allowed-in-c99)
I had referred this question, which was how I came to know about it's deprecation.

Comment: This [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309845/721855) provides alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetshttps://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Comment: Sorry but isn't that meant for files?

Comment: @User1426833: Yes, including `stdin`.

Comment: Yes, you use `stdin`.:)

Comment: @User1426833: `fgets` works on *streams* (like almost every other stdio library function), meaning it can work with standard input as well, you just have to specify it explicitly - `fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin )`.